# Pandas:Replacing binned columns with representative value efficiently

Tags: pandas, performance, binning

I want to bin data and select a specific aggregate for each bin.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
  'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
  'B': [1, 2, 3, 4],
})
groups = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2, labels=False)
group_reps = df.groupby([groups]).agg(A=('A', 'mean'))
# ... some magic happens here to replace values in A by group_reps ...
# 
# expected result
# A, B
# 1.5, 1
# 1.5, 2
# 3.5, 3
# 3.5, 4
```

How can this be implemented efficiently for data of size close to machine memory?

Comment: `df['A'] = df['A'].groupby(groups).transform('mean')`?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was what I was looking for. Struggled with merge, join, lookup...
Would you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alter one column, you can just handle it separately. Also, `transform` helps you align the aggregation with the original index:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].groupby(groups).transform('mean')
```